# setting an NSTextView

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nsattributedstring

How can I set an `NSTextView` to an `NSAttributedString`? I do not want to use a textConainer, and I tried:

```
[myTextView insertText:myMutableAttributedString];
```

but it didn't work. Nothing happened...not even a warning or a runtime error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you verified that `myTextField` is not `nil`?

Comment: Yes, I Have verified myTextView is not nil.

Answer (score 14):

Textview must be editable to insert.

```
[myTextView setEditable:YES];
[myTextView insertText:myMutableAttributedString];
[myTextView setEditable:NO];
```

Comment: 'insertText:' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.11 - Use -insertText:replacementRange: from NSTextInputClient instead. Since the method is designed to be used solely by the input system, the message should never be sent to a text view from applications. Any content modifications should be via either NSTextStorage or NSText methods.

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 2.2:

`myTextView.textStorage?.setAttributedString(myMutableAttributedString)`

In Objective-C:

`[[myTextView textStorage] setAttributedString:myMutableAttributedString];`

Answer (score 3):

You should call `-setString` with an empty string before calling that method (otherwise you're inserting text into a null string object):

```
[myTextView setString:@""];
[myTextView insertText:myMutableAttributedString];
```

Comment: It didn't Work. Not even anything reporting a problem in the console.

Answer (score -2):

the textView is createed programmatically? if you load the NSTextView from xib,it will bi fine.